# how to display data in front end in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, backend, nestjs

I have data in my database and I already implement backend API services. I'm trying to display the data in my front end and render it but I'm not sure why it's not displaying.
Any recommendations or help will be really appreciated.

One of my Backend Get method

```
@Controller('helpSection')

export class HelpSectionController {
    constructor(private readonly helpSectionService: HelpSectionService) {}

    @Get()
    getHelpSection():Promise<HelpSectionEntity[]>{
        return this.helpSectionService.getHelpSection();
    }
```

One of my FrontEnd HTTP Get

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getHelpSection() {
    return this.http.get<HelpSection[]>(`${environment.api.chart}/helpSection`).pipe(first());
  }
```

Just for testing I did it like this in my component

TS

```
import {HelpService} from '../../core/services/help.service'

  constructor(private HelpService: HelpService) {}

  helpSection$ = this.HelpService.getHelpSection();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.HelpService.getHelpSection().subscribe(() => {
    } )
  }
```

HTML

```
 {{helpSection$ | async}} // this display just [object Object]

<div *ngFor= "let help in helpSection$ | async">{{help.sectionName}}</div> // This is not showing anything
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This means your front-end binding is wrong. You see object, object for the json key value pair. The binding should spell the key name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{helpSection$ | async}} // this display just [object Object]
```

For this, data has been returned as an array of objects, so you have to bind it using the object's keys to see the value.

```
<div *ngFor= "let help in helpSection$ | async">{{help.sectionName}}</div> // This is 
not showing anything
```

For this, use "of" instead of "in": `"let help of helpSection$"`. The "help" will be member of array when use "of", and just an index of that member when use "in" (means you have to use {{helpSection$[help].sectionName}}).

Answer (score 0):

your service is returning you `HelpSection[]` , I assume from there

```
return this.http.get<HelpSection[]>(`${environment.api.chart}/helpSection`).pipe(first());
```

So you have a help section model, why don't you use it later?

**TS**

```
import {HelpService} from '../../core/services/help.service'

import {HelpSection} from '../../..' //import it from where it is.

  constructor(private HelpService: HelpService) {}

  helpSection$ = this.HelpService.getHelpSection();
  helpSections : HelpSection[]
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.HelpService.getHelpSection().subscribe( (data:HelpSection[]) => this.helpSections = data )
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor= "let help in helpSections">{{help.sectionName}}</div>
```

**Note:**

1)Your **HelpSection** model must have id and section name (like your json) if you want to make it usable in HTML

2)In **HelpSection** make sure same capitalization is given as html (in ngfor {{}} ) [ helpSection/helpsection ]

3)You see, I didn't use async anymore, if you try my style you don't need async pipe HTML but If you come from observable but not from just a array like me then you must use async pipe in HTML